# Install YonaCMS on Xampp error

Tags: xampp, phalcon

I have installed YonaCMS (a phalcon CMS) on Xampp through composer

But after install site get error with template. Css not load and url seem not work right. I think there must be configured .htaccess or something like that. Anyone has installed YonaCMS on Xampp please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the site URL in the config file:

Set `base_path` in `app/config/environment/development.php` (If you are using production environment then edit `app/config/environment/production.php`)

eg:

```
<?php

return [
//'base_path' => '/',
'base_path' => 'http://localhost/yona-cms/public/',

'database'  => [
    'adapter'  => 'Mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'yona-cms',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
],

'memcache'  => [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 11211,
],

'memcached'  => [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 11211,
],

'cache'     => 'file', // memcache, memcached
];
```